# How is this bathroom ventilation fan attached?

Tags: bathroom, removal, fans

I'm trying to replace a fan in my bathroom.The old one is a **NuTone 668RP**.  I've managed to get all of the innards out of the old fan but can't figure out how the housing is attached. I don't see any screws or anything and it seems to be attached from the top. It's a downstairs bathroom so I can't get to the attic.

[image: photo of fan enclosure]

There's a stud on the "bottom" side (in the photo) but the side is not attached to the stud. I stuck my screwdriver up there and ran it along all four sides. Must be attached to the top somehow.

Comment: What make and model is the fan?  Probably it was installed before the sheetrock was.

Comment: @wallyk Thanks. I've added the photo. It just wasn't an option in the mobile site. Let me see if I can find the make and model.

Comment: Flanges outside the box attached to studs?

Comment: No. As you can see I stuck a screwdriver up all sides and bent it in a bit. As far as I can tell it's attached from the top.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the same model on Amazon so I'm just going to replace the motor, fan, and light.